# AWS: Dynamo DB first request has high write latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using AWS Java SDK to create an adapter to connect, save and query to Dynamo DB.

I am getting irregularity in latency as shown below:-

Case 1 -> For the first write request (after deployment on ec2) it takes around 50-100ms and then subsequent calls take 8-10ms.

Case 2 ->Also if the ec2 is let ideal for sometime (4-5 mins at least), it again shows the same behaviour.

Can I reduce the high latency shown in both cases or at least in case 2 when the ec2 is let ideal. Can ClientConfiguration would be helpful here?

Comment: Are you sure that this latency is produced by DynamoDB? Maybe it's your Java runtime which needs time to get ready? How did you collect the measurements?

Comment: I am just calculating the time for calling the dynamo DB API. It does not have any java logic. Also if I call the API again, it takes less time (16-20ms)

Comment: This is probably due to the initial call creating an `HttpClient` instance. Subsequent calls are using the cached instance so they are much faster. After some idle time the cashed object is released and a new call has to create it again.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the HttpClient instance from releasing?